# What does "grounded" conducting sphere placed in an initially uniform electric field mean? Why the resultant field change?

Tags: electrostatics, potential, conductors, boundary-conditions

Consider this example of an electrostatic boundary value problem. Let an uncharged hollow conducting sphere of radius $R$ be placed in an initially uniform electric field, $\vec E=E_0\hat{z}$, along the $z$-axis. Such a uniform electric field is easy to set up by using two large oppositely charged plates kept parallel to the XY plane and separated by a small distance. The electric field will induce charges on the conducting sphere which in turn distorts the resultant field in a region near the conducting sphere. The problem is to find out the resultant potential. Mathematically, I can solve this problem blindly but I don't have a clear idea about how to arrange the specified boundary conditions.

In particular, the problem says, if the sphere is "grounded", the potential on its surface is zero. Of course, being the surface of the conductor, the surface of the sphere will remain at a constant potential. But how does one arrange the set-up so that the potential on the surface becomes zero instead of any arbitrary unknown constant? Feel free to sketch a diagram if it can be explained better.

**Addition after DKNguyen's answer**

After the discussion with DKNguyen, I'm convinced that after grounding, the net charge on the hollow sphere, given by $Q=\int \sigma dS$, must be zero. But this does not mean that the induced surface charge density should be zero. Does it mean that the distortion in the field near the sphere arise due to the nonzero dipole moment?

Comment: Remember that all electric potentials are with reference to some standard.  When there is a ground, that's the reference.   When there is no ground, e.g. the "floating output" of a transformer, the potentials have to be referenced to one or the other output ports of the transformer.

Answer (score 4):

Find an an infinite charge sink, define that potential as your ground/zero potential, then connect your object to it so it shares the same potential.

Comment: Sorry if this sounds stupid. Can I define the floor of the laboratory as an "infinite charge sink" and connect the sphere with a metal wire to the floor? Is this what you suggest? Will this bring the sphere and the floor at a common potential?

Comment: @Solidification If your floor was conductive and enormous enough. But the Earth is better (it's called ground for a reason), and the power grid and building grounds have metallic earthing network to better distribute charge to the somewhat conductive soil. Unless you're on a ship, then maybe the ship or the saltwater ocean.

Comment: Many thanks! In the situation described above, there will be some induced charges on the sphere, and they remain stuck on the sphere even after "grounding" has been done. But if we connect two objects at different potentials (here the sphere and the earth) shouldn't the free charges flow before the potential is equalized?

Comment: @Solidification Equalizing is the whole point. And what happens when you try and equalize with something infinite?

Comment: Well, I would think that charges will flow to the infinite sink making the sphere neutral.

Comment: @Solidification What happens is that charge moves in *or* out until the potential is equal to the infinite sink. And the the incoming or outgoing charge does not change the potential of the infinite sink because infinite. Thus, after equalizing your object does not change potential even if you try to inject, extract or redistribute charge.

Comment: Let me see if I really understand the situation here. Here, after grounding, the total surface charge $Q=\int \sigma dS$ will be equal to zero but it would have a nonzero dipole moment due to the distribution of charges. This is responsible for the distortion of the electric field near the sphere (even after grounding).

Comment: In your context, I guess it would be that the sphere is now immune to influences from the applied electric field which I assume makes certain conditions static and known for calculation. So the sphere can influence the field lines but the field can't influence the sphere. I don't see why the sphere would have a dipole moment since it's grounded (you can't locally redistribute charge in it once grounded such that a potential gradient exists within it) but double check. I am not the most physiscy.

Comment: I am changing the "solid sphere" to "hollow sphere". Hope that does not alter any of our discussions.

Comment: @Solidification Not to me it doesn't. I have to review how grounding works on a Faraday cage.